# Styling Lists with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on an un-ordered list. I have searched all over the internet for a good tutorial but I cannot find one. I want to display it inline and have a border line in between each `<li>` item. Now I am just unsure of the standards for styling lists. Do I use padding/margins to position the `<li>` items? If so do I apply it to the `<ul>` container or `<li>` or `<a>`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. If your question got answered then please [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), otherwise it isn't clear whether you're already satisfied with one of the provided answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using margins, borders, and float.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.liClass
{
  float:left;
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-left:10px;
  border-right:thick double #ff0000;
}
.lastLi
{
  float:left;
  padding-left:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li class="liClass">one</li>
<li class="liClass">two</li>
<li class="lastLi">three</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why don't you use ul and li in your styling?

Comment: @user1174762 - For a couple of reasons. If `ul` and `li` are used then it affects a broad range of those html objects, and I may want to use them elsewhere without this style. Also, I can assign class names to my html objects dynamically if I want. Furthermore, using `ul` and `li` is actually slower than using class names because css must search the dom for every ul, and then every li.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `float:left;` to `<li>` and style as needed.

Comment: But if i apply it to <li> then the border line overflows out of the <ul> contaner

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block` to make the list items appear side-by-side (it is more reliable than `float: left`), then add borders or whatever else you want - maybe a `width` and some `margin`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: inline-block` to avoid having to mess with clearing floats:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZehJN/